# NFS permission denied

Tags: mount, nfs

I start NFS service on a server in a different city, and the setting in the /etc/exports as below:

```
/data/shared 10.2.6.*(rw,sync)
```

When I mount the NFS directory,it throws an error:

```
mount: ..... failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
```

When i change the setting in the /etc/exports on the remote server as below:

```
/data/shared 10.2.6.12(rw,sync)
```

It works well.

Why i use a ip pattern, it failed? Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` wildcard only works with (sub-)domain entries. For a range of IP addresses, you need to give NFS the subnet base address and netmask in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation). For more information, see the "Machine Name Formats" section of the [exports(5) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports).